# HTML entities in User Feed's title

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, feed

I've just had a look at [my user feed in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/13508) and my first name is not displaying correctly in the title: I see `&#193;lvaro` rather than `Álvaro`. The source code looks like this:

```
<title type="text">User &amp;#193;lvaro G. Vicario - Stack Overflow</title>
```

It seems that input is HTML-encoded twice in the `<title>` tag... It looks okay in the rest of the feed:

```
<name>Álvaro G. Vicario</name>
```

or

```
<name>&#193;lvaro G. Vicario</name>
```

So text is converted into HTML entities zero, one or two times :-?

(Is it even necessary to use HTML entities? **Á** is a valid character in UTF-8 anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the next build, these will no longer be double-encoded.